# Problem with datagridviewcomboboxcell

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, winforms

I have `DataGridViewCombobox` column in my winform. i have bound that comboboxcolumn from database by setting its `DataSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` property.

i want to set `DisplayMember` based on `ValueMember`.  just like we do in normal combobox like

```
Combobox.SelectedValue = "12"
```

I tried following

```
gridAttendance.Rows[0].cells[2].value = dsAttendance.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Id"].ToString();
```

but it doesn't work...

> "It throws an error saying datagridviewcomboboxcell value is not
>   value"

i also tried handling `DataError` event of `GridView`, but still it doesn't work

please suggest me, how can i do it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible in a `DataGridViewCombobox` column - I wanted to do this some time ago and failed.

My solution was not pretty but it worked:- I had a standard `combobox` that was hidden on the form and a hidden column containing your data Values. When the user clicked into the cell it would populate the combobox on the fly and position it over the current cell. (I also had to account for the scroll events and move the combobox accordingly)

When the combobox loses focus populate the cell we started editing with the current text and the hidden column with the value of the standard combobox.

Like I said it was not pretty!